# NEHotspotConfigurationErrorDomain Error on some devices

Tags: ios, swift, networking, wifi

I've implemented a WiFi auto-join feature in my app -> Click a button and connect to a named SSID. This works on some devices but also fails on others - meaning it won't even show the Apple pop up asking to join the network. The device might be the same device model, same iOS but fails on some and not on others. This is the error that I see being returned when it fails:

```
Error Domain=NEHotspotConfigurationErrorDomain Code=10 "cannot modify system configuration." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=cannot modify system configuration.
```

This is the code used to attempt auto-join:

```
let WiFiConfig = NEHotspotConfiguration(ssid: "MYSSID")
WiFiConfig.joinOnce = true

NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(WiFiConfig) { error in 
 if error == nil {
     //success
 } else {
    //fail
 }

}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Jennie

Comment: Things you can check. 1) Make sure WiFi is turned on for that device. 2) Check to see if they are already connected to the WiFi network. 3) Place the device in airplane mode and then turn airplane mode off and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you. All is in order. It doesn't make sense. It knows its not connected to the network but won't auto join to it.

Comment: I an app that uses this feature. One thing I had to take into account was that multiple SSID's where available in the same location.  So I would perform a check to see if they where already on a WiFi connection and if so it would not attempt to make the connection. If they have a Mac they can go in to WiFi and remove the ssid as bad saved copy my exists. Last resort is to reset network settings on those devices and see if they can connect then.

Comment: I have a specific SSID that the app connects too. It should and does (on many devices) prompt with the Apple prompt to connect to that network but on some, it doesn't and returns an error. That's what I can't resolve. Why the error? What does that error mean?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this is unique to our devices using an Embedded Event Manager with a SSID prefilled on the register. That SSID cannot be joined to via the Auto-join feature.

Comment: So whats the solution for that ?

Comment: Not yet, but do have any idea if wifi device requires any specific configuration ?